# $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \ln\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)$ convergence or divergence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

This sum is convergence or divergence?

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \ln\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)$$

What I 've tried

- Divergent test : inconclusive, limit is $0$
- Comparison Test : inconclusive, larger term is divergent

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \ln\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right) < \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{n+1}$$

- Limit Comparison Test : inconclusive, limit is $-1$ for $b_n = 1/n$
- Ratio Test : inconclusive, using L'hopital's rule and the limit is $1$

Comment: Limit comparison test with the harmonic series is *conclusive* as you already have computed that the ratio of $\log(n/(n+1))$ and $1/n$ converges to $-1$. And on top of all, you may appeal to the direct computation of partial sums $$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \log\left(\frac{k}{k+1}\right)=-\log(n+1).$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a telescoping sum $\sum_{n\ge 1}(\ln n-\ln (n+1))=\ln 1-\ln\infty=-\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Try writing this sum for a particular $n$, and using properties of logarithms $\ln \frac{a}{b} = \ln a - \ln b$. Then think about limit.

Comment: oh it's that easy doing this way. thank you